# Android: Javascript to rotate an image using Angle

Tags: javascript, android

I'm creating one application in android to rotate an image using angle in html file.
I need JavaScript to rotate the single image in html page. Could anybody post the code please.

My code is

```
<div>
        <img id="Rose" src="Rose.jpg" style="margin:20px 80px;align:left"></img>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out css3's new [transform rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform) methods:

```
<style>
#elem
{
 transform: rotate(20deg);
}
</style>
<div id='elem'>Hi</div>
```